# Получение усредненного значения

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

Есть таблица вида, размер ~10т записей:

`timestamp                │ value
─────────────────────────┼──────────
2017-01-17T10:47:13.757Z │ 12.34
2017-01-17T10:48:23.261Z │ 15.65
2017-01-17T10:51:13.254Z │ 17.56`

Есть отдельно список времен Z, ~50 точек. Нужно получить таблицу вида

`z[i],t0,v0,t1,v1`

где z[i] - точка из списка,  данные из таблицы, с максимальным временем не превышающим z[i],  - c минимальным временем но большим z[i].  Те найди значения которые предшествуют и сразу следуют за нужной точкой. Если времени до или после не существует, то пусть это t0,v0 или t1,v1 будут равно NULL.

Вопрос 1. Где лучше всего держать данные для таблицы Z. Например можно на время расчета заводит временную таблицу, а потом ее уничтожить.

Вопрос 2. Как правильно написать SQL запрос который сделать нужную выборку.

PS База sqlite, все работает под node.js Задача такая:
Нужно построить график температуры. Данные с датчиков складываются в таблицу в произвольный момент. Разница между записями может быть от 10 секуд до 30 минут. Хочется же получить усредненные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Создавать таблицу или нет - решайте сами, если предполагается один и тот же набор Z использовать несколько раз, то лучше создать. А можно и прямо в запросе указать список значений.

```
with Z(t) as (
  values('2017-01-17T10:49:00.000Z'),
        ('2017-01-16T10:49:00.000Z')
)
select t, substr(p,1,24) t0, substr(p,25) v0,
          substr(n,1,24) t1, substr(n,25) v1
  from (
    select t,
           (select cast(tab.timestamp as text)||"value"
              from tab where tab.timestamp<Z.t
             order by tab.timestamp desc limit 1) p,
           (select cast(tab.timestamp as text)||"value"
              from tab where tab.timestamp>=Z.t
             order by tab.timestamp limit 1) n
      from Z
  ) A
```

Из минусов - все результаты возвращаются текстовыми полями, нужно приводить к требуемому типу. С числами это не проблема `cast(xx as real)` сделает опять числовое значение, а вот обратно в timestamp почему то приводить не хочет.

Тест на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/79d61/17)

Comment: Могу ли отказаться от таблицы Z и сделать sql запрос, если таблица Z представлят из себя времена от одной даты до другой с шагом X минут? Имеет ли смысл отказаться от типа datetime в пользу целого числа?

Comment: @Константин Да, с целым числом будет явно проще. тем более вы можете тогда сгруппировать данные по времени целочисленно деленному на N взять минимумы-максимумы - вот вам и интервалы в N секунд

Comment: Можешь на пример показать?
Пусть к примеру таблица выглядить примерно так:

`
timestamp|value
1| 1.23
7| 4.56
13|7.86
...
`
надо нужно найти ближайшие значения для шкалы от 0 до 20 с шагом 5